# How can I prevent hidden (password protected) Excel sheets from being viewed?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel document where I would like to hide and protect some sheets. The document is shared with approx. 100 partners. We have nothing major to hide but it would help to keep some bits hidden.

These hidden sheets have previously been accessed by opening in Openoffice/mac format.

I understand a determined person will always be able to get in but it would be good to prevent that where possible.

Would some code that runs on opening the document add an extra level of security?

Thanks.

Comment: Look into [Sheets.visible = xlVeryHidden](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197786.aspx).

Comment: Why this solution is put as comment, not the answer ? Answer is displayed on statistics, and can be marked as 'solved'... As for now this question still is displayed as 'not resolves with no answers'. Scott - please - don't take me wrong is not for you, it's general - I see this very often...

Comment: I think I agree with @Scott Craner, it is a helpful comment but not a solution. Although the Sheets.visible = xlVeryHidden might help a bit if the doc is kept in Excel I don't think it will stop the hidden content being visible when opened in OpenOffice or Numbers (mac).